# Salesforce: How to Concatenate multiple fields if they are not blank

Tags: if-statement, merge, salesforce, field, concatenation

Problem: I want to concatenate 5 fields which hold user names and separate them with a comma, but only if they are not blank.

I tried:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_1__c),"", ", TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_1__c"))&
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_2__c),"", ', TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_2__c"))&
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_3__c),"", ", TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_3__c"))&
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_4__c),"", ", TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_4__c"))&
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_5__c),"", ", TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_5__c"))
```

But this literally returns "'TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_1__c)" rather than the field ", John Doe"

How do I get the if function to insert the field, rather than the literal text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the function `TEXT()` in your string literal.

```
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_1__c),"", ", "&TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_1__c))&
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_2__c),"", ", "&TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_2__c))&
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_3__c),"", ", "&TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_3__c))&
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_4__c),"", ", "&TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_4__c))&
IF(ISBLANK(Co_Signatory_Number_5__c),"", ", "&TEXT(Co_Signatory_Number_5__c))
```